# Fazer crop quadrado de uma imagem

Tags: php

Estou tentando realizar o crop de faces de uma foto mas ainda não consegui achar uma fórmula matemática que me ajude a deixar o crop quadrado.

As informações que tenho são:

- Foto
- Posição das faces das pessoas da foto (width, height, top, left)

Apesar das informações das posições das faces ser realmente somente da face de cada pessoa, eu consegui aumentar as laterais para aparecer mais a cabeça completa da pessoa. Então se eu tenho um crop de uma face com as dimensões 80x120 eu aumento em duas vezes esse tamanho e recalculo o top e left da seguinte forma:

```
$sizes['width'] = $sizes['width'] * 2; // Ganhando margem no crop
$sizes['height'] = $sizes['height'] * 2; // Ganhando margem no crop

// Recalculando top e left
$sizes['left'] = $sizes['left'] - ($sizes['width'] / 4);
$sizes['top'] = $sizes['top'] - ($sizes['height'] / 4);
```

Acontece que essas posições não tem o width e height iguais. Eu precisava deixá-los iguais porém reposicionando o top e left para o crop ficar "centralizado".

Ainda considerando o exemplo acima, eu precisava conseguir que o width e height com 120px (maior lado) e o top e left fossem recalculados para a face da pessoa ter o crop centralizado.

Não estou achando alguma fórmula para resolver essa questão.

Eu tentei descobrindo o maior lado e recalculado o top ou o left da seguinte forma:

```
if ($sizes['width'] >= $sizes['height']){
    $bigger = 'width';
    $sizes['left'] = $sizes['left'] - ($sizes['width'] - $sizes['height'] / 2);
} else {
    $bigger = 'height';
    $sizes['top'] = $sizes['top'] - ($sizes['height'] - $sizes['width'] / 2);
}
```

E no crop eu fazia:

```
$image->crop($sizes[$bigger], $sizes[$bigger], $sizes['left'], $sizes['top']);
```

Infelizmente o crop não fica ajustado. Alguma sugestão?

Obrigado.

Comment: Se eu entendi, o objetivo é fazer o crop ficar centralizado tanto na horizontal quanto na vertical? Além disso vc quer fazer o width e o height iguais. Então o crop seria quadrado?

Comment: Exatamente, porém não posso perder a face centralizada nisso.

Comment: Alterei na pergunta acima onde tento recalcular o top ou left de acordo com o lado maior para a pergunta ficar mais clara a maneira que tentei fazer.